How to define a fixed space between dot and the next word of the following sentence?
The spacing between . and the next word in line differs between the lines.
In this example it is the case for: . Gustav and . Carl.
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm,right=25mm,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\linespread{1.}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
Hans Hans Hans Hans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans. Hans Hans    Hans Hans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans. Hans Hans Hans Hans. Hans HansHans Hans. Carl Hans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans. Hans Hans Hans Hans Hans HansHans Hans    HansHans Houses Houses HansHans Hans Hans. Gustav HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans   HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans   Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans. HansHans Hans HansHans Hans   HansHans Hans HansHans Hans Hans
\end{document}   

Which package/command could define the same distance between .<->Word in the document?

It's due to justification, because every interword space is either stretched or shrinked by the same factor. In your case, the effect is emphasized because spaces after end-of-sentence periods are widened due to the default setting of \nonfrenchspacing, which results in more stretching in the case you point to.
Compare the result you get with the same paragraph after declaring \frenchspacing.
Of course, you would declare \frenchspacing in the preamble.
(I commented out the width option that's ignored anyway by geometry, as you already specify left and right margin. I also used \noindent in order to emulate the first nonindented paragraph.)
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  left=35mm,
  right=25mm,
  %width=150mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=20mm
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}

Hans Hans Hans Hans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans. 
Hans Hans    Hans Hans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans. 
Hans Hans Hans Hans. Hans HansHans Hans. Carl Hans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans. 
Hans Hans Hans Hans Hans HansHans Hans    HansHans Houses Houses HansHans Hans Hans. 
Gustav HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans   HansHans Hans HansHans Hans 
HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans   Hans HansHans 
Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans. HansHans Hans HansHans Hans   
HansHans Hans HansHans Hans Hans.

\frenchspacing

\noindent
Hans Hans Hans Hans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans. 
Hans Hans    Hans Hans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans. 
Hans Hans Hans Hans. Hans HansHans Hans. Carl Hans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans. 
Hans Hans Hans Hans Hans HansHans Hans    HansHans Houses Houses HansHans Hans Hans. 
Gustav HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans   HansHans Hans HansHans Hans 
HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans   Hans HansHans 
Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans HansHans Hans. HansHans Hans HansHans Hans   
HansHans Hans HansHans Hans Hans.

\end{document}   



This is expected behavior: TeX is making the right margin line up, which requires different levels of kerning in each line.
If you want the spacing to be the same in every line, you need to allow the margins to be "ragged" (the \raggedright command will do this, as will the flushleft environment).
